# After a fork, if a user opens an incompatible GUI/CLI, what information is presented to the user which says they are using old software?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, hard-fork, fork-notification

Now we are on 0.14.x software, what would happen if someone opens a 0.11.x, 0.12.x or 0.13.x GUI/CLI?

Also, when Monero forks again later in 2019, what will the 0.14.x GUI/CLI present to the user?

Answer (score 1):

When starting the daemon, `monerod`, or one of the command line wallets (`monero-wallet-cli`, `monero-wallet-rpc`), if you are running an old version, it prints a warning message telling you an update is needed. It's worth noting that it does this by checking your blockchain height against the hard-coded fork heights, not by calling some remote update server.

I'm not as familiar with the GUI, but presumably it warns you also.

Comment: So if you're using the CLI and haven't updated you get a warning, but you continue to download blocks from the old chain? If this is right, I think I read somewhere that when you update your software, it pops-blocks (deletes) back to a block height before the fork. Then when block height catches up to the forking block height, it starts downloading blocks from the latest chain. Is this correct?

Comment: No, if you're on the wrong chain, you'll need to manually pop blocks.

Comment: Thanks. I'll explore what the GUI does unless someone else pipes up.